# How to follow email conversations?

Tags: gmail

Sometimes people create a new blank e-mail to respond to an old email conversation, which makes my job more difficult because I have to find the last conversation to remember what they are talking about.

1. What is the best way to fix this?
2. I want Gmail to show emails in the inbox by email-address. If that makes any sense, i.e., in the inbox I want to see emails by sender, and when I click on a line in the inbox, it will show me all that the person ever sent me, in only one page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Gmail doesn't support sorting by sender however their search bar can be very helpful for this.

There have several key words such as FROM: TO: SUBJECT: LABEL: ....
If you're looking for an email from Joe Blow you can search for all his email by

- FROM:Joe Blow
- FROM:joe.blow@email.com
- FROM:Jow
- ...

For more info about the keywords or how to use them see [Google advanced search](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7190).